# Hiding page numbers from pagination in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic components with working pagination displaying props in a table.

This however shows all the page numbers which is not ideal I would like only a few to be seen.

e.g 1-2-3-4-5-20 so that it does not take up too much space.

This is the component itself.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AllAlerts extends Component {
  state = {
    currentPage: 1,
    alertsPerPage: 8,
  };

  componentDidMount() {}

  handleClick(number) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: number,
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Logic for displaying alerts
    const { currentPage, alertsPerPage } = this.state;
    const indexOfLastAlerts = currentPage * alertsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstAlerts = indexOfLastAlerts - alertsPerPage;
    const currentAlerts = this.props.alerts.slice(indexOfFirstAlerts, indexOfLastAlerts);

    const renderAlerts = currentAlerts.map((alerts, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <div>
            All Title {alerts.title}
            <li>All ID {alerts.id}</li>
            <li>All user Id {alerts.userId}</li>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    });
    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(this.props.alerts.length / alertsPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number) => {
      return (
        <button key={number} id={number} onClick={() => this.handleClick(number)}>
          {number}
        </button>
      );
    });

    return (
      <>
        <>All Alerts</>
        <br />

        <form class="example" action="/action_page.php">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
          <button type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </form>

        <>{renderAlerts}</>
        <>{renderPageNumbers}</>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default AllAlerts;
```

From my understanding I would change this in this part of the code.

```js
const pageNumbers = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(this.props.alerts.length / alertsPerPage); i++) {
  pageNumbers.push(i);
  //Only push 1-5 and last which has to change depending on page number
}
```

I have tried a few different approaches all not achieving what I would like.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the index `i` of the loop fits your condition

```
const pageNumbers = [];
const numPages = Math.ceil(this.props.alerts.length / alertsPerPage);
for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
  //Only push 1-5 and last which has to change depending on page number
  if (i <= 5 || i == numPages)
    pageNumbers.push(i);
}
```

But probably you should show the currentPage and the one before and after to, otherwise you won't be able to jump to the next or previous page

```
const pageNumbers = [];
const numPages = Math.ceil(this.props.alerts.length / alertsPerPage);
for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
  if (i <= 5 || //the first five pages
      i == numPages || //the last page
      Math.abs(currentPage - i) <= 1 //the current page and the one before and after
     )
    pageNumbers.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to loop over page numbers, using the counter that react map method gives you can check how many buttons you have created and when then are more than five you stop creating buttons

```
{
  pageNumbers.map((number,count)=>
 count <5?
 <button
      key={number}
      id={number}
      onClick={() =>this.handleClick(number)}
    >
      {number}
    </button>:
 null
 )
}




{pageNumbers.length >5? //next button here : null }
```

You then can go ahead and check the length of number of pages if creater than button you created you add next button

You shoulld update current page to state then check the current page if it is the first element in yhe page numbers else add previous button